# SQL Server grouping a timestamp by hour but keep as date format (don't want to pull hour out)

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I want to group a bunch of time stamps by day, by

```
CONVERT (datetime, CONVERT (varchar, dbo.MEASUREMENT_Battery.STAMP, 101))
```

it produces for me a "day" stamp that SQL Server still views as a date and can be sorted and used as such.

What I'm trying to figure out is if it's possible to do the same thing by hour. I tried

```
CAST(DATEPART(Month, STAMP) AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(Day, STAMP) AS varchar) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(Year, STAMP) AS varchar) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(Hour, STAMP) AS varchar) + ':00:00.000'
```

and this "works" but SQL Server doesn't view this as a date anymore so I can't sort properly.

The end result I want is right though: ex: `9/9/2015 9:00:00.000`

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question into some readable form.  Provide your full SQL statement, sample data and the desired result.  Right now it's practically incomprehensible.

Comment: Especially if the range of overall values is small, you'll get much better results by creating a virtual range table for greater-equa/less-than comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT convert into a string, until you absolutely have to "present" the result.

CONVERT() or FORMAT() return string representations of temporal information

The following method returns a datetime value truncated to the hour without resorting to string manipulation (and hence fast).

```
select
    dateadd(hour, datediff(hour,0, dbo.MEASUREMENT_Battery.STAMP ), 0)
  , count(*)
from dbo.MEASUREMENT_Battery
group by
    dateadd(hour, datediff(hour,0, dbo.MEASUREMENT_Battery.STAMP ), 0)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56980/5)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MEASUREMENT_Battery
    ([STAMP] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO MEASUREMENT_Battery
    ([STAMP])
VALUES
    ('2015-11-12 07:40:15'),
    ('2015-11-12 08:40:15'),
    ('2015-11-12 09:40:15'),
    ('2015-11-12 10:40:15'),
    ('2015-11-12 11:40:15'),
    ('2015-11-12 12:40:15'),
    ('2015-11-12 13:40:15'),
    ('2015-11-12 14:40:15')
;
```

NOTE: the output below for column [Stamp] is the default display

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56980/5/0)**:

```
|                            |   |
|----------------------------|---|
| November, 12 2015 07:00:00 | 1 |
| November, 12 2015 08:00:00 | 1 |
| November, 12 2015 09:00:00 | 1 |
| November, 12 2015 10:00:00 | 1 |
| November, 12 2015 11:00:00 | 1 |
| November, 12 2015 12:00:00 | 1 |
| November, 12 2015 13:00:00 | 1 |
| November, 12 2015 14:00:00 | 1 |
```

If you absolutely insist on dipay of a date/time value a paricular way, then you may add the display format in the select clause (but not needed in the group by clause!)

```
select
    FORMAT(dateadd(hour, datediff(hour,0, dbo.MEASUREMENT_Battery.STAMP ), 0) , 'MM/dd/yyyy HH')
  , count(*)
from dbo.MEASUREMENT_Battery
group by
    dateadd(hour, datediff(hour,0, dbo.MEASUREMENT_Battery.STAMP ), 0)
```

Comment: ...although one of the reasons for avoiding the cast to string is to enable the use of indices, and doing the date math will also prevent indices from being used.

Comment: This worked. I was simply trying to sum or avg timestamp data by day or hour while still keeping the date time data type for use in parameters in excel and sorting. It looks like I should revisit how I do my day grouping for efficiency purposes. I will change to Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that when you use the DateTime Style 101 (at the end of the second CONVERT) the Date will be converted to mm/dd/yyyy and the time to 00:00:00.000 always as stated here an:
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Now, from what I understand from your question is that you would like to include the hour as well and this can be done like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(STAMP , 'MM/dd/yyyy HH') + ':00:00.000'
```

**Note:**

- ':00:00.000' is optional and is just for a nicer output.
- This only works in SQL Server 2012 and later version.

Testing with some test date we will see that we get the expected result:

```
-- Drop temp table if it exists
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T

-- Create temp table
CREATE TABLE #T ( myDate DATETIME )

-- Insert dummy values
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ( '2015-12-25 14:00:00.000' ) -- 14
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ( '2015-12-25 14:00:00.000' ) -- 14
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ( '2015-12-25 15:00:00.000' )
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ( '2015-12-25 16:00:00.000' )
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ( '2015-12-25 17:00:00.000' ) -- 17
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ( '2015-12-25 17:00:00.000' ) -- 17

-- Select query
SELECT COUNT( myDate ), MAX( FORMAT( myDate , 'MM/dd/yyyy HH') + ':00:00.000' ) FROM #T
GROUP BY DATEPART( hour, myDate )
```

Output:

```
2   12/25/2015 14:00:00.000
1   12/25/2015 15:00:00.000
1   12/25/2015 16:00:00.000
2   12/25/2015 17:00:00.000
```